# Tkinter, variables and functions

Tags: python, math, tkinter, binomial-coefficients

Basically I am trying to build a Tkinter window that accepts 4 values and prints in a new Label the result which is calculated by function `P_n(s,n,v,h)`

I simply can't get it to work. Here is the code.

```
from Tkinter import *

def binomialco(p,k):
  Sum = 1
  Pro = 1
  for i in range(0,k):
      Sum = Sum*(p-i)
  for i in range(1,k+1):
      Pro = Pro*i
  return float(Sum)/float(Pro)


def B(s,n,v,h):
  arithmitis = binomialco(n-1,s)*(v*h)**s
  paronomastis = 0
  for i in range(0,s+1):
      d= binomialco(n-1,i+1)*(v*h)**i
      paronomastis+=d
  B=arithmitis/paronomastis
  return B

def P0(s,n,v,h):
  athroisma = 0
  for i in range(0,s+1):
      dent= binomialco(n-1,i)*(v*h)**i
      athroisma+=dent
  athroisma = athroisma**(-1)
  return "{:.2%}".format(athroisma)

def P_n(s,n,v,h):
  paragodas_1=binomialco(n-1,s)
  athroisma_2=paragodas_1*((v*h)**s)*P0(s,n,v,h)
  var.set("{:.2%}".format(athroisma_2))
  print var



def B_2(s,n,v,h):
  pano=(n-s)*v*h*P_n(s-1,n,v,h)
  kato= s+pano
  return pano/kato


root=Tk()

label_1=Label(root,text="Type value for s:")
label_2=Label(root,text="Type value for n:")
label_3=Label(root,text="Type value for v:")
label_4=Label(root,text="Type value for h:")


entry_1=Entry(root)
entry_2=Entry(root)
entry_3=Entry(root)
entry_4=Entry(root)


button_1=Button(root,text="Calculate",command= lambda: P_n(int(entry_1.get()),int(entry_2.get()),float(entry_3.get()),float(entry_4.get())))


label_1.grid(row=0)
label_2.grid(row=1)
label_3.grid(row=2)
label_4.grid(row=3)

entry_1.grid(row=0,column=1)
entry_2.grid(row=1,column=1)
entry_3.grid(row=2,column=1)
entry_4.grid(row=3,column=1)
button_1.grid(row=4,columnspan=2)


root.mainloop()
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File      "    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1486, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "/Users/harrytou/Desktop/nikoskaievita.py", line 58, in <lambda>
button_1=Button(root,text="Calculate",command= lambda:   P_n(int(entry_1.get()),int(entry_2.get()),float(entry_3.get()),float(entry_  4.get())))
File "/Users/harrytou/Desktop/nikoskaievita.py", line 32, in P_n
athroisma_2=paragodas_1*((v*h)**s)*P0(s,n,v,h)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Values I give are 2,4, 0.03333333333,3 . The result should be 2.26% .

Comment: Please, show us also the error.

Comment: To me, Python is giving me the following error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'`Remember that what you  _get_ from the entries are strings that you have to convert to `int` or `float` to make math operations.

Comment: Yeah sorry the error is what you mentioned. Even if I do try and convert I get: "Can not convert string to float"

Comment: Post your new code and the exact error you are having.

Comment: You have to convert your strings to integers or floats in the callback or function that is called when you click the button to calculate. You are trying to convert _empty strings_ to floats, but you can't do that. You can just convert numerical strings to floats or ints.

Comment: Could you check again? @Rinzler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific problem you mention is due to the fact that `P0` is returning a string like `"7.69%"`. You then try to use that value in the calculation that is failing. That string is what the error message is referring to when it says "can't multiply sequence...": the string is the sequence, and obviously you can't use a string in a calculation like you're doing.  (You also have the problem that you don't define `var` before calling `var.set(...)`, but that's a separate problem).

This problem was easy to find, I merely printed out all of the values in `P_n` before doing the final calculation. This should have been your first step when trying to debug this problem.

Here's some additional advice: your code will be much easier to debug, understand and maintain if you don't use `lambda` the way you are. Have the button call a proper function, and have the function get the values before doing the calculation.

```
def do_calculation():
    e1 = int(entry_1.get())
    e2 = int(entry_2.get())
    e3 = float(entry_3.get())
    e4 = float(entry_4.get())

    P_n(e1,e2,e3,e4)

...
button_1=Button(..., command= do_calculation)
...
```